# Set an array to attribute of an External Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, web-component

My problem is the following:

I would like to load external `Angular` components from a remote server at `runtime`. I manage to do it well thanks to the blog post from [Manfred Steyer](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx)

The thing is that I need to pass some `data` object to the component I am loading at `runtime`. In the post from [Manfred Steyer](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx) he does this but not for objects.

What I am doing step by step:

First I create a separate `Angular` project that for instance takes a data object like this:

Inside `RandomComponent.ts`:

```
Interface Random: {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}[]
@Input() data: Random;
```

Inside `RandomComponent.html`:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let d of data">{{d.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Next I build this component and get a file that looks like: `random-component.bundle.js`. I put this file on a server and render it when needed.

Now in the main Angular project, I want to load this file and pass him a data object. If following the blog from [Manfred Steyer](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/07/29/angular-elements-part-ii-lazy-and-external-web-components.aspx), I would do like this:

```
// creation of element from bundle
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'assets/random-component.bundle.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);

// creation of new element based on selector from bundle
const data = [{name: 'Dave', age: 19}, {name: 'Charly', age: 23}];
const component = document.createElement('random-component');
component.setAttribute('data', data);
```

But I can't set an attribute like this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check the `@Input` name in `random-component` component. You are trying to set the attribute so same name should exist in the component.

Comment: Hello Sunil, sorry, I forgot to mention that the @Input() was called data!

Comment: Did you append `random-component` component in body or some after creation ?

Comment: yes I did... `const content = document.getElementById('content');` `content.appendChild(component);`

Comment: There are multiple checks need to perform for this. What you can do is, just remove everything and keep only plain html stuff and check if at least you can see the component in the page. Setting attribute is next.

Comment: I can already see the component in the page, so for that part it is fine, I just can't pass an array or bind data :)

Comment: Then major job is done. We may need to peform query selector to get the actual component. Can you inspect and share the html DOM structure where the component is added,.

Comment: I basically have this inside a div tag: <div id=‘content’ ></div>! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I meant, inspect your custom component in html. Just check what is the entire structure inside the custom compoent.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I get it! I’ll do this as soon as I get on my computer! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those interested!

Instead of passing an `array`, I pass a stringified `array` with `JSON.stringify(data)`, which returns a `string` I can then pass to the attribute:

**Main component**

```
  const component = document.createElement(identifier);
  component.setAttribute('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  const content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.appendChild(component);
```

**External Component - random.component.ts**

```
  parseData(data: string) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }
```

**External Component - random.component.html**

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let d of parseData(data)">{{d.name}}</div>
</div>
```

It works! But there are some issues with the one-way binding